# Не отображается LaunchImage

Tags: ios, launchimage, xcode7

Не отображается LaunchImage на реальном устройстве. Пробовал делать много чего, устанавливал в настройках в поле Launch Image Source - Use Asset Catalog, а в поле Launch Screen File - свой файл xib (он у меня имел раньше такое расширение в предыдущих версиях xcode, теперь, когда обновился до 7.1, у меня файл Launch Image.storyboard, не замечал раньше какое расширение в новых версиях xcode, это в последней версии xcode теперь не .xib, а .storyboard?) и не работает на реальном устройстве (изображение просто не показывается, именно изображение), если я поставлю какую-нибудь кнопку или label, то это все будет видно, а вот картинку я не вижу. Если я запущу приложение на симуляторе, то картинку видно при загрузке. Картинка не битая, я ее же устанавливал на view controller внутри приложения, она показывается. 
Если я устанавливаю в поле Launch Image Source - LaunchImage, а поле Launch Screen File оставляю пустым, то опять это не работает. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой? Я закинул приложения в itunesconnect, хотел попробовать скачать его оттуда и посмотреть на результат, но результат как и раньше плачевный. Есть какие-нибудь идеи?

Comment: а размер точно правильный? и на все ли поддерживаемые устройства  выставлены изображения?

Comment: Да, я пробовал различные версии, даже добавлял на экран изображение 100х100, оно все равно не отображалось. У меня в проекте подключена библиотека Alamofire, я добавил ее как проект. Мне нужно файл Launch Screen положить в мой основной проект или в Alamofire? И у Launch Screen расширение должно быть storyboard, а не xib? Хотя мои вопросы скорее всего глупы, так как на симуляторе загрузочный экран появляется нормально

Comment: Хм, я этот проект делал еще на yosemite, работало все прекрасно, несколько дней назад скинул его на el capitano, работает не очень, особенно картинки. Причем если я в проекте выберу старую картинку (которую добавлял в проект еще на yosemite), то оно отображается, а если выберу новую (которую добавлял на el capitano), то пусто

Comment: Попробовал импортировать с другого проекта файл launch с расширение xib, добавил на него новую картинку и ничего, пусто, как будто он совсем не видит эту картинку

Comment: Еще одна поправка, xcode совсем не видит изображение, не важно где, в launch screen или просто в какой-нибудь вьюшки

Comment: либо вы что то делаете очень неправильно, либо у вас Xcode глючит. Я бы предложил попробовать удалить всю derivedData, сделать clean, удалить приложение с устройства, даже перезапуститься на всякий случай.

Comment: Если я добавляю это же изображение в проект, но не в xcassets, а рядом с классами, то все отлично работает, такое ощущение, что проект не видит либо путь к изображению в xcassets, либо расширение изображения

Comment: После нескольких попыток я просто закинул изображение в корневую папку проекта, тогда оно работает нормально. Где-то читал, что помогало создание нового проекта и перенос данных в него, но я не очень хочу проверять этот способ, он займет очень много времени.

Comment: а что вас в Assets Catalog есть?

Comment: Весь интерфейс, у меня картинки только здесь хранились, все в png, если это важно

Comment: Что то мы не об одном и том же говорим. Если у вас используется assets catalog то должны быть папки что то типа `/Images.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/` и там должны быть все картинки и файл `Contents.json` в котором информация какая картинка для какого устройства используется.

Comment: Да, в файле contents вот что:
{
  "images" : [
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "lanchScreen.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "lanchScreen@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "lanchScreen@3x.png",
      "scale" : "3x"
    }
  ],
  "info" : {
    "version" : 1,
    "author" : "xcode"
  },
  "properties" : {
    "template-rendering-intent" : "original"
  }
}

Comment: хм. и с xcode картинки видны и target membership у них правильный?

Comment: Да, все верно, через пару дней хочу поставить постарее версию xcode или создам новый проект и перенесу проект туда, напишу если получится

Comment: Попробуйте сделать правый клик на LaunchImage файле, далее Open As -> Source Code и проверьте данные Вашей картинки. Найдите там нужный Вам тэг  <imageView> и проверьте, чтобы параметр image был такой же как имя картинки.